# Dynamic method parameters

Tags: node.js, rethinkdb

I writing a node.js application using rethinkdb as a backend.

To retrieve a json value you can use:

```
r.table('users').get(1).run()
```

That method call will return the full json document, there is however a method that allows you to specify the attributes to retrieve e.g:

```
r.table('users').get(1).pick('firstName', 'lastName').run()
```

I want to make use of this functionality and I have the attributes I want to 'pick' stored in an array. I can't seem to figure out a way to convert this array to a parameter list for the .pick method.

Please advice.

Comment: You can use `.apply`, you just have to pass the right value for `this`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use the native apply method to directly pass the arguments array:

```
r.table('users').get(1).pick.apply(this,yourArray).run()
```

[further reading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Comment: Shouldn't that be `pick.apply(...)` !?

Comment: Thanks, now all I need to do is figure out what to pass as this :)

Comment: I guess it will be `r.table('users').get(1).pick.apply(r,yourArray).run()`